# Accessing the Combo Box from the user control which is used in the form

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, wpf-controls, c#-3.0

I have a form which uses four instances of same user control in separate tabs of my form. When i try to set the items of a combobox used in any user control,
The same combo boxes in the other instances of User control are also getting updated.

Is there any way to stop them from getting updated in instances of user control.

I have used the following Code:
egp is my form.
DCE and DCG are different instances of the user control and Cmb is my comboBox.

```
egp.DCE.Cmb.Text = "datavalue";
egp.DCG.Cmb.Text = "datavalue";
```

Comment: Are they databound to the same thing? If they truly are separate instances then they shouldn't affect each other

Comment: Is `.Cmb` Property static ?